# The difference between Bound Services and Threads

Tags: android

I'm studying Android services because I heard that this is the android recommendation to perform background tasks.

I want to interact with that service, so this is the reason that I've chosen Bound Services (btw, I don't want to run that service indefinitely).

The question is: Why should I complicate myself using the IBinder interface and call my methods via this callback [see official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder)

`@Override 
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service){}`

when I can simply create my custom service? For example, if I want to play some background music in a single Activity I can create this custom (and simple) service:

```
public class MyOwnService {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    MainActivity ma;

    public MyOwnService(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(mainActivity, R.raw.badinerie);
        ma = mainActivity;
    }

    public void play(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(ma, R.raw.badinerie);
                mp.start();

            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void pause(){
         mp.pause();
    }

    public void stop(){
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
    }
}
```

and call my service in a simplest way like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyOwnService myOwnService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myOwnService = new MyOwnService(this);
    }

    public void play(View view) {
         myOwnService.play();
    }

    public void pause(View view) {
        myOwnService.pause();
    }

    public void stop(View view) {
        myOwnService.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your service is not a service. It is just a class with "Service" in its name

Comment: Yeah, but does the same thing

Comment: It does not. Although it might look like that from your perspective because you don't need other service specific functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can create threads and other objects as you need. But your solution has one big issue - Android OS is not aware about your "service". Remember, android can terminate your app process at any time. Suppose your activity goes into background, from the perspective of android os your app process is a good candidate for killing - it only has one not active activity.

Think of the service like a notification to os that your app is doing something important in the background.

If on the other hand your background work should only happen as long as your activity is active you do not need a service. Just to avoid confusion do not use name service in classes that are not really android services.

EDIT: also note that you can start a service manually and then later bind to it. If you have started bound service manually then it will continue running until you stop it.

Comment: *Think of the service like a notification to os that your app is doing something important **in the background**.* I don't think that is correct, since services run on the main thread by default

Comment: Services are started in the main thread, but all serious work has to be done in a background thread. Android platform IntentService is a good example of this. If your work is so small that it can be safely done in main thread then i dont see much point in using a service.

Comment: *all serious work has to be done in a background thread* it is customary but not necessary. *Android platform IntentService is a good example of this* yes but we are talking about services are we not? *If your work is so small that it can be safely done in main thread then i dont see much point in using a service* separation of concerns is a good argument to put even small tasks in (intent)services

Comment: I recommend to use some other ways to "separate concerns". If work is so small that it can be safely run in the ui thread then launching a service is clearly overkill - creating services takes resources.

Comment: @Okas Thank you. It is really useful. But I have a doubt. Again, according to the official docs *A bound service runs only as long as another application component is bound to it*. So if I need a task to work in a background of one activity, it seems to me that I should use a non-bound service

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: As said before, if your task is needed only for a certain activity, do not use service, use asynctask or plain threads. If your task is somewhat independent from single activity, then use a service.

Comment: Yes, but if my task is independent from a single activity then android force me to use an unbound service, because *A bound service runs only as long as another application component is bound to it*. But I want to interact with that service... Is there any solution to keep that service alive other than starting and binding it in the same time?